# How do I set and access application preferences from a phonegap app?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I want to set the URL of my backend as a setting and access that value from an angular controller. The setting should be settable from a "settings" for the app menu for the phone. The app is using phonegap 3.1.0, for android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localStorage option of the Cordova/PhoneGap.

You can set a new value using the setIteam.

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

You can get the value by using getItem.

```
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Based on this you can create a page to present a form to enter and save your settings.